# Hypothesis test for two groups distributed as a Poisson

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, poisson-distribution

I have to do an hypothesis test for two series, both distributed as a Poisson.
The first groups has its mean, and the second another one: i have to test the significance of this difference. Which test should i use?

The t-test for the difference between two means? I try the U-test, but I don't think it's ok cause it's only for continuous distribution, not discrete as Poisson ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze categorical predictors in regression models--including those using Poisson-distributed outcomes. You just need to ensure that you code the categorical variable appropriately (e.g., using *dummy*, *effect*, or *contrast* codes) in order to fit a model that yields interpretable/sensible intercept and slope estimates. Good descriptions of the various coding strategies can be found in West et al. (1996) and Cohen et al. (2013)

**References**

Cohen, J., Cohen, P., West, S. G., & Aiken, L. S. (2013). Applied multiple regression/correlation analysis for the behavioral sciences. Routledge.

West, S. G., Aiken, L. S., & Krull, J. L. (1996). Experimental personality designs: Analyzing categorical by continuous variable interactions. Journal of personality, 64(1), 1-48.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i didn't find free stuff about the ones that you write about. What can you think about a simple statistical test, is there a good one? thanks

Comment: West et al. (1996) is currently freely available on google scholar through a link from semanticscholar.org. And I'm afraid that if you're insistent on having a Poisson-distributed outcome, a Poisson regression with a singleton categorical predictor (dummy, effects, or contrast coded) is as simple as you're likely to find.

Comment: thanks for your availability. I don't undestand why are you telling me about a "Poisson regression" instead of using a test for the difference between two means. I have 2 groups of data, with different lenght, and i have to verify to a significance test between these 2 mean. How can i do that with a dummy variable?
Sorry for my question, i'm quite new in this kind of analysis.

Comment: A comparison between two groups can always be represented as a regression model. Just represent the groups with a *dummy variable*, which is 0 for one group, 1 for the other. The a model of form $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 \mathbb{I}_i+\epsilon_i$ represents the means of the two groups, respectively $\beta_0$ and $\beta_0+\beta_1$